# Unable to set the title of a view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have the following code that should set the title of my uiviewcontroller, but its not working. any idea why ?

```
self.title=@"User Login";    
[self setTitle:@"User Login"];
```

Comment: Where are you putting those line of code?, Do you have a navigation bar?

Comment: i have a toolbar with two bar buttons on left and right and in between theres flexible space..

Answer (score 1):

Your view controller has to be pushed by the navigation controller, for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand this correctly...

You have added a **UIToolBar** at the top?

Try adding a **UINavigationBar** instead of a UIToolBar, and your title should work.

UIToolBars normally go in the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

well, heres the solution: since theres a flex space in between the left and right buttons on the uitoolbar, the name was not appearing..i removed the flex space and put my name there. thanks everyone for ur kind suggestions.

Comment: Since you are using a toolbar, you need to put a UILabel in the middle... and use it to display your login name and you can still use your flexible spacing.

Answer (score 0):

- In order to set the title, you need to set the title of the view controller. Even though you do this,the title wont be visible unless you add a navigation controller. This should fix the issue. For this you need to have a navigation controller, and set its title. Then you can hide the navigation controller, if you wish. I have pasted the sample code below.
- Once you set the title of the navigation controller, then you can push the views however you like. See the sample code.

[- The entire code to do this is here](http://kmdarshan.wordpress.com/2012/11/07/answer-to-stackoverflow-question-2-unable-to-set-the-title-of-a-view-controller/)